# Count the number of occurrences of integers in a file using ArrayLists

Tags: java

This is what I have so far, I just have a scanner to read all the numbers from a file of 1000 numbers between 1- 100. I am just a little stuck in which direction I should go.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayListProb
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
   {
      File file = new File("number.txt");
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

      ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000); //declare     ArrayList with 1000 numbers

  while(reader.hasNext()) //add the numbers to ArrayList
  {
     numList.add(reader.nextInt());
  }
  reader.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example that shows how to read string values with Scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\createtable.sql");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1000);
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)) {

            while (reader.hasNext()) // add the numbers to ArrayList
            {
                list.add(reader.next());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

You can read your integers as String values and parse them to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

**Array-list do not support integer for such approach so there are two option either you 
1)You can use Map instead of Arraylist and then execute the following code.**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
while (inputFile.hasNext()){
    Integer next = inputFile.nextInt();
    if (myMap.containsKey(next)){
        myMap.put(next, myMap.get(next) + 1);
    }else{
        myMap.put(next, 1);
    }
}
```

**2)Or you can simple read file as string and then afterward parse it to integer as described in above solution.**